# Form data not added to query string

Tags: html, forms

Form data is not being added to the URL as query string, i.e., something like this `127.0.0.1:8080/room?first=king&last=henry`.

The files `index.html` and `room.html` are the only files in the folder. I serve up the folder with `$ npx serve -l 8080` and it runs on `127.0.0.1:8080`.

The contents of `index.html`

```
<form action="/room.html" method="GET">
  <label for="first">first:</label>
  <input type="text" name="firt">
  <label for="last">last:</label>
  <input type="text" name="last">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

But when I hit submit, it does not add the input values as a query string to the URL.

Interestingly enough when I simply omit the `action="/room.html"`, it does add it.

EDIT: After looking further into it, in the network panel it logs `room.html?first=king&last=Henry` and right after logs `room`. The former has header `Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently`.

Any insight is great. Thanks!

Comment: not the greatest idea to use get for user name and passwords.

Comment: The user name and passwords was just a "placeholder", i.e., just for testing the form html. Let me change to some trivial data so no confusion among readers.

Comment: I just tested your code and it is working so what is different?

Comment: It is the exact same. Hitting submit the url is simply `http://127.0.0.1:3000/room` without any params

Comment: So is something redirecting it back to that page with your server set up? Open up the network panel and watch what happens. (probably need to check the box to preserve log on page navigation)

Comment: ^To your question, let me check. @epascarello, did you run it on the `$ npx serve -l 8080` or any port of your liking? It seems if I use `$ python3 -m http.server 8080` to serve up the file, the form works perfectly fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248124/discussion-between-owen-murphy-and-epascarello).